# Plot two catplots in same figure using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot two catplots in same figure. I tried to use subplot() function but no result. 
Here is the code I am using for ploting one catplot at a time.

**First Catplot**

```
fig, axs =plt.subplots(2,1)
sns.catplot(x = 'day',y = 'count',data=day_of_month_count,
            kind ='bar',
            height = 8 , aspect= 1.5,ax=axs[0])
```

[image]

**Second Catplot**

Here is a second catplot am plotting :

```
sns.catplot(x = 'day',y = 'count',data=day_of_month_count,
           kind ='bar',
           height = 8 , aspect= 1.5,ax=axs[1])
```

[image]

**Goal**: 
***plot to catplots in the same figure ( one next to the other)***

I tried something like this (with subplot), but it does not work.

```
fig, axs =plt.subplots(2,1)
sns.catplot(x = 'day',y = 'count',data=day_of_month_count,
            kind ='bar',
            height = 8 , aspect= 1.5,ax=axs[0])
sns.catplot(x = 'month',y = 'count',data=month_of_the_year_count,
           kind ='bar',
           height = 8 , aspect= 1.5,ax=axs[1])
```

Any alternatives? solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, next to each other would require 1 row 2 columns. Then the following method works normally as expected.

Here you have to close/hide the axis returned by the `catplot`. This can be done using the correct index and `plt.close`. The indexing/numbering of figures starts from 0. Here is a sample answer.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", kind ='bar', data=exercise, ax=axs[0])
sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", kind ='bar', data=exercise, ax=axs[1])
plt.close(2)
plt.close(3)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Something is ,wrong . I am executing the same code as yours. add at the end plt.savefig('xxxx.png') . What i get as an output is a figure with two axis ( but no catplots)

Comment: @mouni93 Can you try just copy pasting my code in a fresh terminal and run it?

Comment: executing same code through terminal, and adding savefig at the end  gives same output as yours.  Don't know what is wrong with my jupyter. I execute the script through jupyter notebook ( !python test.py ) and it works fine . Thanks

Comment: I downvoted this because its a clear misuse of the seaborn catplot function. The problem with such workarounds is that they will spread around and create new problems for people who are unaware of the implications. Later, once the bug that figure level seaborn functions accept a pass-through argument for `ax` is fixed, they will all start asking questions again for why their code doesn't work any more. Instead people should accept the fact that catplot creates its own figure and either use catplot's `col` argument, or create two barplots individually.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks for justifying the downvote. Appreciated!